# How do programs that redraw the terminal work?

Tags: c, terminal

I'd like to write a game of life application, just for fun/practice.
How do processes (like `top` or `watch` for example) redraw the screen, but not generate a whole load of output (so that when I scroll up, it's just one frame, not every single frame generated by the process)?

Is this language dependent, or is it something done through OS calls?

I'd like to do it in C, so I can practice memory sharing by adding 'rabbits' that eat the objects.

Comment: I would suggest you use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: In MSVC you can use [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) so that your console text overwrites the previous generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not language-dependant; it is related to the terminal (probably a terminal emulation in your case). Initially terminals wouldn't allow such features, but later, some special "characters" had such effect (clearing the screen, moving the cursor, etc.). Libraries (like [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) are aware of such codes, that may vary according to each emulated terminal; have also a look at [Termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) or [Terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)).

All these features rely on an environment variable called TERM; each piece of software is able to know what kind of terminal is emulated. Of course libraries like ncurses adjust their behaviour according to it. Just have a look at

```
echo $TERM
```

which will probably output something like `xterm` (which is a *de facto* standard) or `linux` (other standards are `vt100`, a little older, or `screen` which is a great tool).

Answer (score 2):

To clear the terminal in C you can do this:

```
printf("\033[0;0H\033[2J");
```

Taking this apart:

- `\033` is the ascii escape sequence for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key
- `[0;0H` sets the cursor position to the top left of the screen
- `[2J` clears everything in the screen

`\033` can also be written as `\x1b` or `\e` on certain systems. As a side note, you can do this in Java and other languages so it's not C-specific.

Comment: Yes, but it is better not to use directly codes (see my reply); using a library is better.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel ncurses implements these codes.

Comment: Yes, but according to the detected TERM; very unusual terminals with other codes may exist.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel This works on all ANSI and VT100 terminals.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel Also, I have just tested my method with different terminals where `$TERM` is `screen`, `linux`, `xterm` and `vt100`. It works exactly as expected.

Comment: MSVC just prints the control text with its non-printing characters as best it can.

Comment: I agree and I often do it myself for small projects, but using a library is a better way to follow standards; using ANSI/VT100 codes directly is not standard. See https://www.proteansec.com/linux/blast-past-executing-code-terminal-emulators-via-escape-sequences/ "Many programs use escape sequences directly to introduce different functionality like changing the color of the important text to red. In reality, programs should not emit terminal escape sequences manually, but should rather use ncurses, tput or reset utilities."